# Массивы – предзаполнение и заполнение

Tags: javascript

У меня задача сделать плейсхолдеры для товаров на время загрузки.
Не могу найти правильный подход. Первое, что пришло в голову и что выдает гугл это отдельный блок на время загрузки, но в таком подходе происходит дерганье при рендеринге, что в моём случае дергает страницу и вызывает дальнейшую подгрузку. И это происходит во всех шаблонизаторах vue/angular/react. Поэтому в голову пришла мысль cделать предзаполнение массива с последующим его заполнением.

```js
let products = [{id: 245}, {id: 233}, {id: 333}];

// ... функция подгружающия данные
// добавляем в массив пустые элементы, которые будут рендерится как плэйсхолдеры
products.push(...[{}, {}, {}]);
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(newItems => {
    // заменяем пустые на товары
    let count = -1;
    products = products.map(p => {
      if (p.id) return p;
      else {
        count++;
        return newItems[count] || {};
      }
    }).filter(p => p.id); // удаляем пустые
    console.log(products);
  });
```

Но получается у меня очень костыльно, количество захардкожено, если приходит больше элементов, то не добавляется итд итп. Поэтому вопросы:

1. Как добавить `n` пустых объектов в массив (без цикла)?
2. Как заполнить и "переполнить" массив, заменяя только пустые элементы?

Или может есть интересней подход?

Comment: по первому вопросу возможно поможет [`fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill): `new Array(5).fill({})`

Comment: @Grundy, спасибо! По второму пришла мысль просто удалить пустые и запушить новые – `products.filter(p => p.id).push(...newItems)`, но вот плаваю в вопросе рендеринга - будут ли перерендериваться все предидущие элементы? Во vue v-for.